# Calculation of the number of microseconds in Ada

Tags: real-time, ada, epoch, milliseconds

in C langage we have get_usec() which gives us the number of microseconds since the start of the current second.
-Speaking of the "current second" necessarily refers to time reference which is often EpochTime.
-In Ada.Calendar package, I see Seconds or Clocks functions by example with ability to split & get the seconds.
But how to get the number of microseconds since the start of the current second, please?
Thanks
Mark

Comment: Do we have get_usec in C? I can't find it in the C11 draft standard, nor does a web search bring up any promising hits.

Answer (score 2):

The packages Ada.Calendar and Ada.Calendar.Formatting provide the information you will need.

```ada
with Ada.Text_IO;             use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Calendar;            use Ada.Calendar;
with Ada.Calendar.Formatting; use Ada.Calendar.Formatting;

procedure Main is
   Now     : Time            := Clock;
   Seconds : Second_Duration := Sub_Second (Now);
begin
   Put_Line
     ("Sub seconds since current second: " &
        Second_Duration'Image (Seconds));
end Main;
```

The output of one execution of this program is:

Sub seconds since current second:  0.655316600

In this execution the value indicated 655316.6 microseconds.

Answer (score 2):

Note that Ada.Calendar is for local time, and may jump backwards. If it's available (are there any post-83 compilers that don't provide it?), you'll be better off using Ada.Real_Time [ARM D.8](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/aarm12_w_tc1/html/AA-D-8.html):

```
Now : constant Ada.Real_Time.Time := Ada.Real_Time.Clock;

Count : Ada.Real_Time.Seconds_Count;
Sub   : Ada.Real_Time.Time_Span;
...
Ada.Real_Time.Split (T => Now, SC => Count, TS => Sub);
```

Now Count contains the number of whole seconds since the epoch and Sub contains the fraction of a second in addition to Count. Ada.Real_Time.To_Duration converts a Time_Span to Duration, allowing you to multiply it by 1E6 to get microseconds.

Comment: If you are using a pre-Ada2020 compiler you will find it difficult to output the value of a Time_Span variable in human-readable format.

Comment: @JimRogers, did you see the part where Jeffrey mentions `Ada.Real_Time.To_Duration`? That was there in Ada95.

Comment: I saw Ada.Real_Time.Duration but I could not verify that this was the Duration defined in Ada.Calendar. The LRM does not stipulate that Ada.Real_Time depends upon Ada.Calendar. I only saw the following "It is recommended that Calendar.Clock and Real_Time.Clock be implemented as transformations of the same time base."

Comment: Duration is a fixed-point type declared in Standard. Ada.Calendar.Day_Duration is a subtype of Duration.

Answer (score 1):

It can also be done (of course) without Ada.Calendar.Formatting, like this for example:

```
with Ada.Calendar; use Ada.Calendar;
...
type Seconds_In_Day is range 0 .. 86_400;
-- Or use Integer if it is 32 bits.

Now : constant Day_Duration := Seconds (Clock);
Subsec : Duration := Now - Day_Duration (Seconds_In_Day (Now));
...
if Subsec < 0.0 then
   -- Conversion of Now rounded up instead of down.
   Subsec := Subsec + 1.0;
end if;
```

with the result in Subsec.

But using Ada.Calendar.Formatting.Sub_Second is shorter, and may be better (faster or more accurate) for all I know; I did not compare the two methods.

Answer (score 0):

Many thaks for yours answers.

Using all yours examples, i made some trials, one is below :

```
with Ada.Text_IO;   use Ada.Text_IO;

with Ada.Calendar;  use Ada.Calendar;
with Ada.Real_Time; use Ada.Real_Time;

procedure Display_Current_Year is

   --need to precise the origin package Ada.Real-Time else ambiguous
   Now         : Ada.Calendar.Time := Clock;
   
   Now_Year    : Year_Number;
   Now_Month   : Month_Number;
   Now_Day     : Day_Number;
   Now_Seconds : Day_Duration;
   
   Current_Real_Time : Ada.Real_Time.Time;
   Time_Span         : Ada.Real_Time.Time_Span;
   Seconds_Count     : Ada.Real_Time.Seconds_Count;
   
   Hour : float;
      
begin

   --- Ada.Calendar
   Split (Now,
          Now_Year,
          Now_Month,
          Now_Day,
          Now_Seconds);
          
   Put_Line("Calendar : Date du jour = ");
   Put_Line ("Current year  is: "
             & Year_Number'Image (Now_Year));
   Put_Line ("Current month is: "
             & Month_Number'Image (Now_Month));
   Put_Line ("Current day   is: "
             & Day_Number'Image (Now_Day));
   Put_Line ("'Current' seconde   is: "
             & Day_Duration'Image (Now_Seconds));
   New_Line;

   --Ada.Real_Time; 
   Current_Real_Time := Ada.Real_Time.Clock;

   Ada.Real_Time.Split (T  => Current_Real_Time,
                        Sc => Seconds_Count,
                        Ts => Time_Span);

   Put_Line ("Real_Time : Seconds_Count = " & Seconds_Count'Img);
   Hour := (float(Seconds_count) / 3600.00);
   Put_Line ("Hour since seconds origin : " 
                                     & (Hour'Img));

end Display_Current_Year;
```

> ```
> with result :
> ```

```
$ ./display_current_year
Calendar : Date du jour = 
Current year  is:  2022
Current month is:  2
Current day   is:  27
'Current' seconde   is:  68625.325897000

Real_Time : Seconds_Count =  30953
Hour since seconds origin :  8.59806E+00
$
-Results for calendar are OK, but why 30953 seconds !!
Where does GNAT take the Epoch, if this is, in this case, please?
Thanks
Mark
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a dirty trick where you define a record My_raw_duration_Type : whole_part, fraction_part, both U32.  Define Unchecked_Conversion To_Raw (Ada.Real_Time.Duration, My_Raw_Duration_Type).  Then take the result of that and call it My_Raw_Duration.  The milliseconds result you want is integer(float(My_Raw_Duration.Fraction_Part)/float(4*1032**2) * 1000.0);

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).